# Rspec, Capybara feature testing forms rendered from partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am trying to write a feature test using rspec and capybara. I have a form that is contained within a rendered partial, and when capybara is unable to find the form elements in the spec. Any ideas on how to get capybara to render the partials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, for I have done something embarrassingly dumb. I needed to have the user signed in to see the form content. Everything is working now.